Why is my system using --illegal-access=permit option when running java app on openjdk1.8?
My system specs:
===================

Linux 4.18.0-553.16.1.el8_10.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 8 17:47:08 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
openjdk version "1.8.0_422" OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.422-b05, mixed mode)
Apache Maven 3.8.8

The error I receive:
===================
command mvn clean package

[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.422.b05-2.el8.x86_64/jre/bin/java
--illegal-access=permit -jar
Unrecognized option: --illegal-access=permit Error: Could not create
the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred.
Program will exit.

The question:
===================
Where is this java option --illegal-access comming from? I can't find this anywhere on my system. I also have a openjdk17 version on my system. Does this interfere here?

Are you using IntelliJ maybe?

I do but also from the CLI.
